# Does the Windows subsystem for Linux creates a virtual network?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I realize that a process running in my Ubuntu Terminal running in Windows 10 that opens a port was accessible from the host PC but not from the rest of my local network. I did some checks in the Firewall department and I even stop all of them and yet no change.

My network is essentially a wireless router running in 192.168.0.1, the host PC (the one running the process) is on 192.168.0.139. BUT, If run the command `ip addr show` from within the Ubuntu terminal running the process I get this local IP instead: 192.168.75.62. What is this? a subnet created by the Windows subsystem for Linux? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, WSL is running in a Hyper-V VM with a virtual NIC.  That NIC is NAT'd behind the Windows network stack.

That 192.168.75.62 is the virtual NIC address.  It will change on each reboot of Windows.  If you run `ipconfig` in PowerShell or CMD, you should also see a corresponding 192.168.75.1 labeled as "Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL)".

If you have Windows Professional or higher, you can examine the Hyper-V interface in more detail by installing the Hyper-V feature.

As for accessing the WSL instance from the local Windows machine or from other devices on the network, because the WSL interface is NAT'd behind the Windows interface, it requires port forwarding.  For local access, WSL seems to do some automatic port forwarding, but this is not the case for elsewhere on the network.  That requires not only manual port forwarding, but also inbound firewall allowance.  See [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150#issuecomment-504209723) and the overall thread for more details.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65387586/11810933) for some other options on other possible methods.

Answer (score 1):

> Will WSL 2 be able to use networking applications?
>
> Yes, in general networking applications will be faster and work better
> since we have full system call compatibility. However, the new
> architecture uses virtualized networking components. This means that
> in initial preview builds WSL 2 will behave more similarly to a
> virtual machine, e.g: WSL 2 will have a different IP address than the
> host machine. We are committed to making WSL 2 feel the same as WSL 1,
> and that includes improving our networking story.

(source: [WSL 2 FAQs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-faq))